# PHPExcel : graph working on LibreOffice but not on Excel

Tags: php, phpexcel

I'm currently using [PHPExcel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel) (v1.8.0) to generate an xlxs file with datas and graph.

It works well when I open the file on LibreOffice, but in Excel it throws and error : "*Excel found unreadable content in ..*"

When I "repair" the file in Excel, I have my datas but not the chart, and this message : "*Removed Part: /xl/drawings/drawing1.xml part.  (Drawing shape)*"

Strange fact : when I *Save As .xls* from LibreOffice, I can read the file with the chart in Excel.

You can download a sample file on my DropBox : [download here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3uyae85shwd0lz5/export_36_20150306_120823.xlsx?dl=0)

Here is the whole code to generate my *.xlsx file :

```
<?php

require_once('PHPExcel.php');


/* increments $nb times a column letter */
function getCol($col, $nb) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < $nb; $i++) {
        $col++;
    }
    return $col;
}

$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
$objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();

$sheetlabels = array("Groupe d'activité", "Données réelles", "Données simulées");
$sheetdatas = array();
$sheetdatas[] = array_map("utf8_encode", $sheetlabels);
foreach ($groups as $k => $group) {
    $sheetdatas[] = array($group, $data_real[$k]*1, $data_simulated[$k]*1);
}
$sheetdatas[] = array("Total", $total_real*1, $total_simulated*1);


$nbdatas = count($groups);
$startCol = 'B';
$startLine = 25;

$objWorksheet->fromArray($sheetdatas, null, ($startCol . $startLine));

$endCol = getCol($startCol, count($sheetlabels)-1);
foreach(range($startCol, $endCol) as $columnID) {
    $objWorksheet->getColumnDimension($columnID)->setAutoSize(true);
}

$currentLine = $startLine + count($groups) +1;
$objWorksheet->getStyle($startCol . $currentLine . ':' . $endCol . $currentLine)->getFont()->setBold(true);

$styleArray = array(
    'borders' => array(
        'allborders' => array(
            'style' => PHPExcel_Style_Border::BORDER_THIN
        ),
    ),
);
$objWorksheet->getStyle($startCol . $startLine . ':' . $endCol . $currentLine)->applyFromArray($styleArray);


$currentCol = getCol($startCol, 1);
$currentLine = $startLine + 1;
$endLine = $startLine + count($groups) + 1;
$objWorksheet->getStyle($currentCol . $currentLine . ':' . $endCol . $endLine)->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode('# ##0.00');

$currentCol = $startCol;
$dataSeriesLabels = array(
    new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('String', 'Worksheet!$' . (++$currentCol) . '$' . $startLine, NULL, 1), //  Données réelles
    new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('String', 'Worksheet!$' . (++$currentCol) . '$' . $startLine, NULL, 1)  //  Données simulées
);

$currentLine = $startLine + 1;
$xAxisTickValues = array(
    new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('String', 'Worksheet!$' . $startCol . '$' . $currentLine . ':$' . $startCol . '$' . ($currentLine + $nbdatas - 1), NULL, $nbdatas)  //  Tous les groups
);

$dataSeriesValues = array();
$currentCol = $startCol;
$currentLine = $startLine + 1;
foreach ($sheetlabels as $sheetlabel) {
    if ($sheetlabel) {
        $currentCol++;
        $dataSeriesValues[] = new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('Number', 'Worksheet!$' . $currentCol . '$' . $currentLine . ':$' . $currentCol . '$' . ($currentLine + $nbdatas - 1), NULL, $nbdatas);
    }
}

//  Build the dataseries
$series = new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries(
    PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries::TYPE_BARCHART,       // plotType
    PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries::GROUPING_CLUSTERED,  // plotGrouping
    range(0, count($dataSeriesValues)-1),           // plotOrder
    $dataSeriesLabels,                              // plotLabel
    $xAxisTickValues,                               // plotCategory
    $dataSeriesValues                               // plotValues
);

$plotArea = new PHPExcel_Chart_PlotArea(NULL, array($series));

$legend = new PHPExcel_Chart_Legend(PHPExcel_Chart_Legend::POSITION_RIGHT, NULL, false);
$title = new PHPExcel_Chart_Title('Consolidation ' . utf8_encode($label));

$chart = new PHPExcel_Chart(
    'chart1',       // name
    $title,         // title
    $legend,        // legend
    $plotArea,      // plotArea
    true,           // plotVisibleOnly
    0,              // displayBlanksAs
    NULL,           // xAxisLabel
    $yAxisLabel     // yAxisLabel
);

$chart->setTopLeftPosition('B2');
$chart->setBottomRightPosition('L22');

$objWorksheet->addChart($chart);


$filename = "export_" . $indicator_id . "_" . $date . ".xlsx";
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
$objWriter->setIncludeCharts(true);
$objWriter->save($dir . '/' . $filename);

?>
```

I have no clue where I made a mistake at this point.

---

**Resolution**

Alright, I figured out what the problem is.

Seems like you **have to** specify the *plotDirection* in order to not have an issue in Excel

```
$series = new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries(
            PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries::TYPE_BARCHART,       // plotType
            PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries::GROUPING_CLUSTERED,  // plotGrouping
            range(0, count($dataSeriesValues)-1),           // plotOrder
            $dataSeriesLabels,                              // plotLabel
            $xAxisTickValues,                               // plotCategory
            $dataSeriesValues                               // plotValues
        );
        $series->setPlotDirection(PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries::DIRECTION_VERTICAL);
```

I made a [pull request](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/pull/527) to the GithHub project to set a plotDirection default value.

Comment: Not sure what can be the issue here,but same was happened with me and it's start working after re installation of ms office.

might be the issue because of corrupted excel source.

Comment: @Trupti I don't think it comes from Excel itself, as I tried from multiple computers / versions and the issue still occurs.

Comment: Alright,in my case it was working on other system except my system.

Comment: Have you re-checked the XML data structure generated for the graph ? Maybe it's not fully valid and that's why libreoffice accepts it ( it fixes it on it's own ) but msexcel rejects. Is there any data with specific symbols? Quotations?

Comment: @DainisAbols I figured out what the problem was. See the **resolution** part

Comment: I suggest you write and accept this as your own answer for future reference then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Resolution**

Alright, I figured out what the problem is.

Seems like you **have to** specify the *plotDirection* in order to not have an issue in Excel

```
$series = new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries(
            PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries::TYPE_BARCHART,       // plotType
            PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries::GROUPING_CLUSTERED,  // plotGrouping
            range(0, count($dataSeriesValues)-1),           // plotOrder
            $dataSeriesLabels,                              // plotLabel
            $xAxisTickValues,                               // plotCategory
            $dataSeriesValues                               // plotValues
        );
        $series->setPlotDirection(PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries::DIRECTION_VERTICAL);
```

I made a [pull request](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/pull/527) to the GithHub project to set a plotDirection default value.